# Disabling hover effect on "active" class

Tags: html, css, hover, moodle

I'm styling a [moodle theme](https://moodle.org/?lang=pt_br) and put this effect on nav:

[image]

But i don't want it to appear on "Active" nav: Only appearing on **server** and not on **appeareance**

CSS:

```css
.nav-item .nav-link {
  position: relative;
}

.nav-item .nav-link::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 50%;
  width: 0%;
  height: 1px;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  transition: 0.4s ease-out;
}

.nav-item .nav-link:hover::after {
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
```

The "tree" of menu element:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use `:not()` to prevent a specific class from being selected.

```
.nav-item .nav-link:not(.active):hover::after {
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
```

---

Here's an example of how to use `:not()`

```css
.class {
  color: red;
}

.class:not(.bad_class) {
  color: green;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<p class="class bad_class">Hello</p>
<p class="class bad_class">Hello</p>
<p class="class">Hello</p>
<p class="class bad_class">Hello</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply create another class for the other nav items and remove the :hover from the Apperance nav item

Answer (score 0):

You can use this CSS trick

```
.active.nav-link:hover::after {
  width: 0;
}
```

there should be no space between these two classes.
It says that if an element has these two classes then what CSS should appear.